# Plugins are not available in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am getting below exception when i am running jenkins.war file.
I am not able to find plugins.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown S
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown So
        at hudson.model.DownloadService.loadJSON(DownloadService.java:171)
        at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateDirectlyNow(UpdateSite.java:180)
        at hudson.model.UpdateCenter.updateDefaultSite(UpdateCenter.java:2191)
        at jenkins.install.SetupWizard.init(SetupWizard.java:168)
        at jenkins.install.InstallState$3.initializeState(InstallState.java:105)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.setInstallState(Jenkins.java:1057)
        at jenkins.install.InstallUtil.proceedToNextStateFrom(InstallUtil.java:9
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:947)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:231)
```

Comment: Any firewall dropping your outbound connections?

Comment: Actually i am facing problem related to proxy settings